Why does electron's orbital momentum have weaker magnetic field than the electron's spin momentum?
The orbital magnetic field is caused by electrons orbiting the atom. If I'm right the magnetic field of the spin is caused by larmor precession. Here I don't understand, why is magnetic field of spin, stronger than orbital magnetic field; Do this two momentums have different velocities?

"spin velocity" does not make sense for an electron, which is a point particle. The spin of an electron is an intrinsic property, like mass. It does not describe motion through space.

These don't answer your question, but they might help - Spin and Angular Momentum, Spin, orbital angular momentum and total angular momentum

Are you asking why the g-factor is $2$ for the spin magnetic moment?
